# Flutter: How to "auto serialize to JSON" IconData objects?

Tags: json, serialization, flutter

I have a simple object looking like this:

```
part 'myObject.g.dart';
@JsonSerializable()
class MyObject {

    IconData data;
    String name;

    MyObject({this.name, this.iconData});
 
   factory Keystroke.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MyObjectFromJson(json);

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MyObjectToJson(this);

}
```

When I try to serialize this using the json_serializable package I get the following error:

> Could not generate `fromJson` code for `data`.
>
> None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.

Any help on that would be appreciated...

Thanks

(I am using the latest SDKs available if that is of any importance... thanks)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could use the **IconData values**

**(codePoint, {this.fontFamily, this.fontPackage, this.matchTextDirection})**

you require instead of the IconData object itself. 
In you UI (or elsewhere) you could then use this object and reconstruct the IconData.

**Or** you have to write to- and from-JSON-methods by your own. You will find articles for that, e.g.: https://medium.com/flutter-community/generate-the-code-to-parse-your-json-in-flutter-c68aa89a81d9